# Visio DrawLine() method is not working as I expect

Tags: c++, vba, visio

Shape.DrawLine Method (Visio) is not working as I expect. It draws the lines where it wants, not in the positions I give. It doesn't matter where it is located the main shape, it always makes the drawings in the same position. Until now I was using Visio 2000 with its SDK, and I didn't have any problem with this function. But now that I have updated to Visio 2016 it is not working as before. What I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

```
x1 = TO_INCH(pEntidad->m_datos_entidad.linea.x1);
y1 = TO_INCH(pEntidad->m_datos_entidad.linea.y1);
x2 = TO_INCH(pEntidad->m_datos_entidad.linea.x2);
y2 = TO_INCH(pEntidad->m_datos_entidad.linea.y2);

hr = elSimbolo.DrawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, laLinea);
```

I'm trying with very basic shapes, for example drawing a rectangle, and I don't get a rectangle

Answer (score 0):

Nerea Murua !

Just check documentation about [DrawLine method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Visio.Shape.DrawLine) syntax, this method have only 4 parameters.

```
expression.DrawLine(xBegin, yBegin, xEnd, yEnd)
```